# Change imaginary unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Is there any way to change the default imaginary unit of `siunitx` to `\mathrm j` instead of `\mathrm i`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key `output-complex-root` defines that, and the default is

```
\ensuremath{\mathrm{i}}
```

Hence,

```
\sisetup{output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathrm{j}}}
```

should do what you want.

For input, you can use both `i` and `j`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathrm{j}}}
\begin{document}
\num{1+2i} \num{1+2j}
\end{document}
```